# Java Util Logger Write Synchronization

Tags: java, logging, synchronization, java.util.logging

Normally in applications (Take web application for example) we have a single instance of the logger created during the startup. It can even be a singleton and it doesn't matter. The important thing is there is 1 instance for the whole application. We use java.util.logger

Now image you have two requests from two different users which throw an exception and we are logging those which get written to the log file. Is the write in these two different requests to the log file synchronized in someway? Or do we need to explicitly synchronize them cause I found in rare cases we got logs which are all mixed up between two requests in the tomcat log file?

I am not exactly concerned about causality here just separation of two log messages.

Comment: The mixed up thing can happen if you call the log twice in 2 consecutive statements. Atomicity is then not guaranteed any more.

Comment: Not in two consecutive statements for sure. It is happening on different requests on different parts of the code

Comment: When I say mixed up I didn't mean one truncated by other but interleaving

Answer (score 7):

You don't need any synchronization, quoting [JavaDoc of `Logger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html):

> All methods on Logger are multi-thread safe.

Note that separate calls from different threads can still be interleaved. It just means that you won't have one message being interrupted and sliced by the other.

Comment: but does that guarantee hold for appenders too?

Comment: @radai: you mean handlers? I can't find a reference, but I'm pretty sure they are safe as well. Can you give an example what do you mean by "*mixed up*"?

Comment: When I say mixed up I didn't mean one truncated by other but interleaving

Comment: @SaiVenkat: log message are printed/saved in the order they were issued. This means if thread context switches, logs from different threads will interleave. In other words, log messages are always sorted by time, not by thread

Comment: So you mean there is a guarantee for causality?

Comment: Sadly, bug JDK-6823527 "java.util.logging.Handler has thread safety issues" reveals there were some thread safety issues fixed in Java 8 in ConsoleHandler,FileHandler,Handler,MemoryHandler,SocketHandler, and StreamHandler https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6823527

Comment: as JDK-6823527 was fixed, this is an argument in favour of thread-safety.